# Pull only rows based on duplicate values of a single column

Tags: sql-server-2008

So, I'm trying to pull only the rows where the WorkerID column has duplicates.

[With this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GaZC.png)

[I would like to pull...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wOqG.png)

I've tried using...

```
Select 
wlpu.id, wlpu.workerid 
from vwWorkerLocalProcessingUnits__c wlpu 
inner join vwLocalProcessingUnits__c lpu on lpu.id=wlpu.LocalProcessingUnitID 
where lpu.BargainingUnit not like '%NABET%' 
and 
wlpu.StatusName like 'Member - Active%' 
group by wlpu.id, wlpu.workerid, wlpu.WorkerFirstName, wlpu.WorkerLastName, wlpu.ProcessingUnit, wlpu.LastProcessedDuesPeriodDate 
having count(wlpu.WorkerID)>=2
```

Comment: I've tried using...

Comment: Table definitions, and a full explanation of the logic you are trying to achieve, would help immensely